# Get player's X and Y position

Tags: python, minecraft

I'm trying to make my Minecraft clone more like Minecraft, so I am trying to add a function that generates chunks, how can I do that?

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
import random
--SNIP--
def Hill():
    Hill_Size = random.randint(0,22)
    HillZ = random.randint(0, 30)
    HillX = random.randint(0, 30)
    for i in range(1):
        HH = 0
        HH += 1
        voxel = Voxel(position = (HillX,HH,HillZ))
        voxel = Voxel(position = (HillX+1,HH+1,HillZ+1))
        voxel = Voxel(position = (HillX+2,HH+2,HillZ+2))
--SNIP--
for z in range(30):
    for x in range(30):
        layer1 = Voxel(position = (x-15,0,z-15), texture=grass_texture)
        layer2 = Voxel(position = (x-15,-1,z-15), texture=dirt_texture)
        layer3 = Voxel(position = (x-15,-2,z-15), texture=stone_texture)
        layer4 = Voxel(position = (x-15,-3,z-15), texture=brick_texture)
Hill()       
app.run()
```

Is there a way I can find my player's position like `print(player. x)`, or can I do something like `x, y = get. player.position()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a conditional statement like this:

```py
if player.x < variable:
    statements
```

Where we can replace the `x` with `y` or `z`.
Put this in the update function and you're good to go.